# Working with enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Since my game has some modes (which should be provided at initialization), so I thought of creating an enum for it. Later on I wanted to get the value of this enum. Below is my code-

```
enum GameMode : short
{
    Stop = 0,
    StartSinglePlayer = 4,
    StartMultiPlayer = 10,
    Debug = 12
}
class Game
{
    static short GetValue(GameMode mode)
    {
        short index = -1;
        if (mode == GameMode.Stop)
            index = 0;
        else if (mode == GameMode.StartSinglePlayer)
            index = 4;
        else if (mode == GameMode.StartMultiPlayer)
            index = 10;
        else if (mode == GameMode.Debug)
            index = 12;
        return index;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = GetValue(GameMode.StartMultiPlayer);
    }
}
```

I am curious to know about a better way to do the same, if exist.

Comment: Any particular reason why do you want to convert this enum to a short value? Enum are much clearer.

Comment: @Steve: the index value, which is returning by `GetValue()` will be used later on inside a mathematical expression. Since the mode names are simple to use, so I created enum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, there is a much easier way. Just *cast* your enum to its underlying numeric data type:

```
value = (short)mode;
```

Comment: Yeah... This is what I was expecting... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple switches like that or if there is different behavior for each mode, then I would recommend using [polymorphism instead of enum with switch](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). If the switch in your example is only place where `GameMode` is used, Heinzi's solution is simpler. But I would at least keep this in mind for the future if you encounter situation where you want to do different stuff with `GameMode` than what you are showing.

Comment: Completely agree with you point. But currently Heinzi's solution is perfect for me. Thanks for the advance info.